# Newton and Secant method using MATLAB

Tags: roots, matlab, newton-raphson, secant

For a homework question I am supposed to be using the Newton and secant methods to find the roots of the function $F (x) = 0.11 + x + 0.8x \sin(\pi x)$ for $n=0$ to $n=12$ with initial guesses $x_0=-1.1$ and $x_1=-0.9$ and displaying the results in vector variables `x_newton` and `x_secant`. So far I have the following code:

```
%Newton method

f = @(x) 0.11+x+0.8*x*sin(pi*x);
df = @(x) 1+0.8*sin(pi*x)+0.8*x*pi*cos(pi*x);
x(1)=-1.1;
tol=1e-14;
for n=1:12
    x(n+1)=x(n)-f(x(n))/df(x(n));
    if ( abs(x(n+1)-x(n)) <= tol*abs(x(n)) )
        break
    end
end
x_newton = x(:)
x4=x(5)

%secant method

x(2)=-0.9
tol=1e-14;
for n=2:13
    x(n+1)=x(n)-f(x(n))/(f(x(n))-f(x(n-1)));
    if ( abs(x(n+1)-x(n)) <= tol*abs(x(n)) )
        break
    end
end
x_secant = x(:)
x4=x(5)
```

However my results from the Newton method and the secant method are extremely different; would someone be able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The secant method uses the approximation
$$
f^{\prime}(x_{n})\approx\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x_{n-1})}{x_{n}-x_{n-1}},
$$
but your code uses the incorrect approximation
$$
f(x_{n})-f(x_{n-1}).
$$

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! Glad it was just a silly mistake. Another part of the question asks us to investigate the rates of convergence of the two approaches but I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I think it's meant to be something to do with the error magnitudes but I'm unsure how to incorporate it into my code. Does anyone have any advice on how to start this?

Comment: This might help: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/lectures/L10-Rates-of-conv-Newton.pdf